# deploying rails app to heroku migrations rake error on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems, migration, heroku

I am attempting to deploy my app to heroku via a windows 7 machine.

I've made it as far as git push heroku master without running into any major issues but when I try to rake the migrations i get the following error

```
$ heroku rake db:migrate --trace
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - /disk1/tmp/13403_23723015091620/.bundle/gems/specifi
cations/activesupport-2.3.8.gemspec
/disk1/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/.bundle/environment.rb:178:in `read'
/disk1/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/.bundle/environment.rb:178
/disk1/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/.bundle/environment.rb:147:in `map'
/disk1/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/.bundle/environment.rb:147
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/disk1/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/config/../config/preinitializer.rb:3
/disk1/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/config/boot.rb:28:in `load'
/disk1/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/config/boot.rb:28:in `preinitialize'
/disk1/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/config/boot.rb:10:in `boot!'
/disk1/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/config/boot.rb:129
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require' /disk1/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/Rakefile:4
/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:238
3:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'
/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19
(in /disk1/home/slugs/211056_9194ad5_13a9/mnt)
```

I should mention, though it could be determined from the above code, that I am using bundler.  Perhaps it is due to this.

I'm at a total loss as to what this could mean. I came across [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410950/heroku-deployment-error), but all the fixes it presented I had already tried and they didn't work.  I am beginning to appreciate why rails deployment is derided so. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already take a look on Heroku's documentation about Bundler at http://docs.heroku.com/bundler ?

Are you sure that your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files are added to your git repository?

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to duplicate this problem:
http://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues#issue/30

The same Rails app will deploy via OS X.

Comment: Response I received from Heroku: "Hi, There's an issue with Bundler and the Gemfile.lock it generates on Windows. If you remove your Gemfile.lock from the repository and push again, it should be fine. You'll see a warning about Gemfile.lock being required in the future, please disregard it. Hope this helps."